# Sprint bugs changed since yesterday

Tags: jira

Is there a way in Jira to find out what bugs that belong to this Sprint were changed since yesterday? I want to use this for out SCRUM summary.

I can find which bugs I changed, and I can expand it to find out which bugs were changed by everyone in the team, but I am only interested about the Sprint bugs that were modified since yesterday.

So, which bugs were added to the Sprint, or which bugs were updated, by anyone (regardless if the person belongs to the team), since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
project = TEST and issueType = Bug and updated > -1d and sprint in openSprints()
```

Would look in the `Test` Project for all `Bugs` updated within the past `1 Days` and the issue is in an `Open Sprint`.

Or you could use perhaps `startOfDay(-1d)` instead of `-1d`.

See the [Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) document from Atlassian.